# Is triple point intersection 'generic' in Teichmuller space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

Let $S$ be a hyperbolic surface of finite type and $\alpha,\beta$ be two closed curves. Consider $X$ to be the set of all those points $\chi$ in the Teichmuller space $\mathcal{T}(S)$ of $S$ such that there is at least one intersection point between the geodesic representative of $\alpha$ and the geodesic representative of $\beta$ which is not a double point.

**Q) Is $X$ nowhere dense in $\mathcal{T}(S)$?**

I think it is true but I can't prove it.

Comment: One has to rule out 3 simple closed curves on a punctured torus meeting at a point, since these will always have a triple intersection at the fixed point of an elliptic involution which sends each curve to its inverse.